# Drupal and Docker with local sync folder

Tags: drupal, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a drupal 8 installation with docker / docker-compose for local development. What I'd like to have is a local folder that is synchronized with the drupal container's `/var/www/html` directory, so I could work locally. What is the best way to achieve that?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.5
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=xxxxx
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxxx
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=xxxxxxx

drupal:
  image: drupal:8.0.4
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map a folder to your dockerhost. Using docker-compose you would have to add "volumes" to your configuration.

The configuration looks like this (see [doc](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#volumes) for detailed explanation):

```
volumes:
  - /path/on/your/host:/path/in/your/container
```

Your configuration would then look like this:

```
drupal:
  image: drupal:8.0.4
  volumes:
    - /path/on/your/host:/var/www/html
  links:
    - mysql
```

cheers,
ceth